# ESRI ArcEngine SDK - Identify sample doesn't work

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#

I'm trying to follow the Identify snippet from the ESRI ArcEngine SDK
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Do_Identify_Snippet/00490000000n000000/

The third line of the tutorial throws a COM exception:

```
public void DoIdentify(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView activeView, System.Int32 x, System.Int32 y)
{
  if(activeView == null) return;
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap map = activeView.FocusMap;
  ESRI.ArcGIS.CartoUI.IIdentifyDialog identifyDialog = new ESRI.ArcGIS.CartoUI.IdentifyDialogClass();  //THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION


{"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F8AAB776-8B1E-11D3-9F7A-00C04F6BC886} failed due to the following error: 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE))."}
```

I expect to run into some trouble using the snippets, but I can't even call a constructor... : (

Any thoughts are appreciated...

Specs: ESRI ArcEngine 10 VS 2010 C#

**Edit:** 
Maybe I don't have access to the CartoUI library.  I also tried this:

```
AdvancedDrawingDialogClass t = new ESRI.ArcGIS.CartoUI.AdvancedDrawingDialogClass();
```

But I got a similar error.

**Edit 2:**
I found out how to do the identification so I'm going to post it for the community.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapControl.LayerCount; i++)
{
  ILayer layer = mapControl.get_Layer(i);
  if (!(layer is IDynamicLayer))
  {
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IIdentify identify1 = layer as IIdentify;
    IArray array = identify1.Identify(geometry);
    if (array != null)
    {
      object obj = array.get_Element(0);
      IFeatureIdentifyObj fobj = obj as IFeatureIdentifyObj;
      IRowIdentifyObject irow = fobj as IRowIdentifyObject;
      IFeature feature = irow.Row as IFeature;
      IGeometry geometry1 = feature.Shape; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the identify UI in arcengine a few years back.  Never really figured it out though.  http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=159&f=1705&t=144001#418493

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only available in Desktop and not Engine, according to the API documentation:
[IdentifyDialog CoClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IdentifyDialogClass_Class/00130000008n000000/)